# Updating a block inside an update hook

Tags: 6, blocks, updating

I want to update the configuration (weight, pages, region) of some blocks within an update function. I know I could do this directly inside the database. Is there a better way of doing this? I scanned http://api.drupal.org, but I didn't find anything like `block_load()` and `block_save()`.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

One of the typical update block configuration tasks was changing the cache flag (before 6.22, that is). You can find updates that mess with the {block} table directly in many projects, including mine: [privatemsg_update_6002()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.install/function/privatemsg_update_6002/6-2).